# User Registration Profile on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, profile

We're currently running a CiviCRM site based on Drupal 7, so as EoL approaches once again we're looking at migrating to Wordpress.

On Drupal we have additional questions added to the user registration form using the CiviCRM User Registration profile option. I'm trying to do the same on Wordpress and it's just not working. I've tried with an imported version of our existing CiviCRM database, and I've tried on a completely fresh install. The fields in the profile with the User Registration option on just don't show up. In fact, Wordpress doesn't show anything other than its standard registration form.

When I try to create a new CiviCRM profile, I notice the the User Registration and User Account options look like the might be crossed out?

[image: Screenshot of the CiviCRM profile settings screen, with the User Registration and User Account options Xed out]

Does WordPress just not support this function at all, or is there some other option or further plugin I need to accomplish it?

Comment: have you compared to what you can see at eg https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fuf%2Fgroup&reset=1&selectedChild=user-profiles

Comment: They are not crossed out - they are selected. What are your users registering for? Or is it that they are registering for access to the site?

Comment: Yes, registering for access to the site. And that demo suggested by @petednz-fuzion doesn't seem to have open registrations enabled, so I can't compare. On Drupal, those options could be turned on or off, but on WordPress I just see a fixed X, and the functionality doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: This issue suggests they are crossed out, not selected: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/wordpress/-/issues/99

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question. Create the profile like normal, but go to advanced settings and require account creation. We have this setup for our memberships.

[image]

Comment: Currently on Drupal our workflow is that CiviCRM injects a profile into Drupal's default user registration form. Whereas this looks like it appends a user registration process to a CiviCRM profile. It would make the migration a bit harder, but it seems like it could be a decent alternative if the former isn't possible. But, is there any way to remove the need for a separate username field? Either by generating a username automatically, or using the e-mail address?

Comment: Yes there are several ways to approach drupal user creation - use 'create drupal user' and have a civicrm profile set for this to get the extra fields. OR use a civicrm Profile and set it to include 'account creation'. OR use a drupal webform and CMS User extension and create the user by adding the contact to a Civi Group or Tag (with the possibility to also immediately log them in)